# Can I limit the amount of System.Threading.Tasks.Task objects that run simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am using Task classes to do multi-threaded computation.

For example:

```
   List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        var task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
        taskList.Add(task);
        task.Start();
    }
```

Is there a way to make only, let's say, 3 tasks to run at most, and the rest to wait?

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property.

[example](http://bembengarifin.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/controlling-the-concurrency-level-using-maxdegreeofparallelism-in-parallel/)

Answer (score 6):

[My blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/limit-the-number-of-c-tasks-that-run-in-parallel/) shows how to do this both with Tasks and with Actions, and provides a sample project you can download and run to see both in action.

## With Actions

If using Actions, you can use the built-in .Net Parallel.Invoke function. Here we limit it to running at most 3 threads in parallel.

```
var listOfActions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Note that we create the Action here, but do not start it.
    listOfActions.Add(() => DoSomething());
}

var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3};
Parallel.Invoke(options, listOfActions.ToArray());
```

## With Tasks

Since you are using Tasks here though, there is no built-in function. However, you can use the one that I provide on my blog.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        StartAndWaitAllThrottled(tasksToRun, maxTasksToRunInParallel, -1, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutInMilliseconds">The maximum milliseconds we should allow the max tasks to run in parallel before allowing another task to start. Specify -1 to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, int timeoutInMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        // Convert to a list of tasks so that we don&#39;t enumerate over it multiple times needlessly.
        var tasks = tasksToRun.ToList();

        using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasksToRunInParallel))
        {
            var postTaskTasks = new List<Task>();

            // Have each task notify the throttler when it completes so that it decrements the number of tasks currently running.
            tasks.ForEach(t => postTaskTasks.Add(t.ContinueWith(tsk => throttler.Release())));

            // Start running each task.
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                // Increment the number of tasks currently running and wait if too many are running.
                throttler.Wait(timeoutInMilliseconds, cancellationToken);

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                task.Start();
            }

            // Wait for all of the provided tasks to complete.
            // We wait on the list of "post" tasks instead of the original tasks, otherwise there is a potential race condition where the throttler&#39;s using block is exited before some Tasks have had their "post" action completed, which references the throttler, resulting in an exception due to accessing a disposed object.
            Task.WaitAll(postTaskTasks.ToArray(), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And then creating your list of Tasks and calling the function to have them run, with say a maximum of 3 simultaneous at a time, you could do this:

```
var listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var count = i;
    // Note that we create the Task here, but do not start it.
    listOfTasks.Add(new Task(() => Something()));
}
Tasks.StartAndWaitAllThrottled(listOfTasks, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks).

To paraphrase, you create a collection of the relevant tasks, then use the ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to control how many get executed at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this one as a generic

```
public TaskThrottle(int initialCount, int maxTasksToRunInParallel)
{
    _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount, maxTasksToRunInParallel);
}

public void TaskThrottler<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, int timeoutInMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class
{
        // Get Tasks as List
        var taskList = tasks as IList<Task<T>> ?? tasks.ToList();
        var semaphoreTasks = new List<Task<int>>();

        // When the first task completed, flag as done/release
        taskList.ForEach(x =>
        {
            semaphoreTasks.Add(x.ContinueWith(y => _semaphore.Release(), cancellationToken));
        });

        semaphoreTasks.ForEach(async x =>
        {
            // It will not pass this until one free slot available or timeout occure  
            if(timeoutInMilliseconds > 0)
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(timeoutInMilliseconds, cancellationToken);
            else
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

            // Throws a OperationCanceledException if this token has had cancellation requested
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Start the task 
            x.Start();
        });

        Task.WaitAll(semaphoreTasks.ToArray(), cancellationToken);
}
```