# How to queue some amount of work so they execute in sequence

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a queue of tasks or work items that needs to be executed in **sequence**, in the background. These tasks will be of the "fire and forget" type, meaning that once they are started, I do not really care if they complete or not, no need for cancellation or status update. If they do not complete, the user will be able to retry or diagnose manually.

The goal is to be able to keep a reference to the queue and only have to do

```
myQueue.Add( () => DoMyStuff() );
```

in order to add something to the queue.

The System.Threading.Task class only seems to be able to queue tasks one after the other, not by referencing a common queue. I do not want to manage the complexity of getting the latest taks and attach to it.

Threadpools do not guarantee sequencing and will execute work items in parallel. (Which is great, but not what I need)

Is there any built-in class that can handle that that I did not think of?

**Edit:** 
We need to be able to add tasks to the queue at a later time. The scenario is that we want to send commands to a device (think switching a light bulb on or off) when the user clicks on a button. The commands take 5 seconds to process and we want the user to be able to click more than once and queue the requests. We do not know upfront how many tasks will be queued nor what will the tasks be.

Comment: A BackgoundWorker and a Blocking Collection?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand: why not using a ConcurrentQueue<ThreadStart> that one single thread (or maybe several) would just myQueue.TryDequeue().Invoke()

Comment: The attached might be of interest : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to automatically execute the latest task inserted in a blocking collection? I can roll my own queuing/dequeuing/execution mechanism, but I really do not want to reinvent the wheel and it seems like something common enough that  a solution would already exist.

Comment: IIRC, you can make the BlockingCollection behave like a stack instead of a queue.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `BlockingCollection`, by default it will use a `ConcurrentQueue` as its internal data structure.  Ensure that any task with prerequisites has its prerequisites added to the collection first.  The `BlockingCollection` can be a collection of `Task`s, some custom item representing the parameters for a method to be called, a `Func<>` or `Action<>` to execute, or whatever.  Personally I'd go with either `Task` or `Action`.

Then you just need to have a single thread that goes through each item in the collection and executes them synchronously.

You can add new items to the queue while it's working and it won't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a queue object as a wrapper around System.Threading.Task. If you limit the number of concurrently executing threads to just 1 in the underlying thread pool, I think your problem is solved.

Limiting the number of executing tasks: [System.Threading.Tasks - Limit the number of concurrent Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks)

Answer (score -2):

How about starting all the threads at the same time and make them listen to a job completion event.

say your threads have id according to the sequence to run, all the threads can start at the same time, but will sleep till they get the job complete/ timeout of the previous job

The Job complete/ timeout event will also help your monitoring thread to keep track of the worker threads

Comment: What if there are 1 million tasks in the queue?  Having threads sleep like this until others finish is really not a good idea in any case.

Comment: True, it will be more efficient to use the Background Worker and a blocking collection as mentioned by Martin James

Comment: Honestly every time I see `Sleep` in peoples' code I die a little inside.  This is not a comment at you, just in general.  Why make that poor thread just sit there doing nothing?  There is almost always a better design.