# Retrieve information from a REST service asynchronously while throttling the number of requests

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a program that needs to get some data from an Atom feed.  I tried two approaches and neither of them worked well.

I've used WebClient to synchronously download all the posts I need, but as there are a few thousand and the service is slow it takes many hours.

I've tried (for the first time) async/await, the new HttpClient and Task.WhenAll. Unfortunately that results in thousands of requests hitting the service and bringing it down.

How can I run say 100 requests in parallel?

Comment: Have you tried HttpWebRequest using the AsyncCallback with BeginGetResponse?

Comment: How is that going to help me?

Comment: From your question, I thought you want to make asynchronous calls? Or do you think this technique, (recommended by Google)  will also overwhelm the service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Threading.Tasks - Limit the number of concurrent Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks)

Comment: Is this a third-party feed or yours?  If third-party, you might look into their services since there is a probability that they have a service that you can request a specific count to return and maybe an offset to create a "paging"-type feature.

Comment: I've looked into the SemaphoreSlim option, but it's more general and complex than what I need. I can partition my list of Urls to download into groups, I just don't know how to express that in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Parellel with ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism

[ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)

Or a BlockingCollection with a bounded collection size

[BlockingCollection Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx)

I would recommend the BlockingCollection

Comment: Thanks Blam. ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism works fine. It seems to be 4 times slower in my case than async/await and HttpClient.GetAsync. I guess switching between the threads is expensive compared to the single IO completion port thread.

Comment: Give BlockingCollection a try.  But it may not be any better.  Not really sure how it handles thread.   For me I like the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a solution already in that you can get a lot done at once.   I'd suggest just adding another layer on top of that which just loops through all of the posts, but only processes them 100 at a time.

Right now you might have:  DownloadAll(List ListofPosts)  Inside of DownloadAll you probably have a wait all at the end.

instead:
For loop from 1 to  ( ListofPosts Count / 100)
   DownloadAll(ListofPosts.Skip(xxx).Take(100));

Obviously not real code there, but then you can do chunks of 100 with little change to your main function.

Comment: May not be so simple if it is a third-party feed.  If they only allow a "DownloadAll", not likely but you never know, you can't really return a subset properly.

Comment: Doesn't sound very efficient. I'd like to keep downloading a 100 posts at any time and not download them in batches.