# How to limit the number of threads for a certain region of code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

```
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
}
```

But, what if I need to limit the number of actions that run in the same time? How do I do that?

Comment: try to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321473.aspx

Comment: MaxDegreeOfParallelism - check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like microsoft's solution here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx.

Example usage for only allowing one thread at a time:

```
 LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
 TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);

 factory.StartNew(()=> 
 {
   //work as usual
 });
```

consider using a BlockingCollection and GetConsumingEnumerable() inside your action for a pretty clean implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx