# Limit the number of Tasks in Task.Factory.Start by second

Tags: c#, task

I've seen a number of posts about limiting the number of tasks at a time ([System.Threading.Tasks - Limit the number of concurrent Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks) is a good one).

However, I need to limit the number of tasks by second - only X number of tasks per second? Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I thought about creating a ConcurrentDictionary, the key being the current second, and the second being the count so far. The doing a check if we are at 20 for the current second, then stop. This seems suboptimal.

I'd rather do something like spin up a task every 1s/20. Any thoughts?

Comment: What if some tasks take more than 1/20s. Should it create a new task?

Comment: Good question, I think for my purposes, 1/20s is sufficent, but if there is an elegant solution for that, that'd be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this can be a starting point. Below sample creates 50 Tasks (running 5 tasks/sec).

This doesn't block the code that creates the tasks. If you want to block the caller until all task have been scheduled, then you can use `Task.Delay((int)shouldWait).Wait()` in `QueueTask`

```
TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(new TimeLimitedTaskScheduler(5));

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var x = taskFactory.StartNew<int>(() => DateTime.Now.Second)
                        .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
}

Console.WriteLine("End of Loop");
```

---

```
public class TimeLimitedTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    int _TaskCount = 0;
    Stopwatch _Sw = null;
    int _MaxTasksPerSecond;

    public TimeLimitedTaskScheduler(int maxTasksPerSecond)
    {
        _MaxTasksPerSecond = maxTasksPerSecond;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        if (_TaskCount == 0) _Sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var shouldWait = (1000 / _MaxTasksPerSecond) * _TaskCount - _Sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (shouldWait < 0)
        {
            shouldWait = _TaskCount = 0;
            _Sw.Restart();
        }

        Task.Delay((int)shouldWait)
            .ContinueWith(t => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => base.TryExecuteTask(task)));

        _TaskCount++;
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

Comment: I have a curious problem - this mostly works well. From time to time, it blows up. When I set max per second to say 5, it's great for about a minute, and then all of the sudden it spikes to say 20-40 for a few seconds, then drops, and then spikes again shortly there after (in a two minute test)

Comment: @Prescott Because This algorithm tries to keep the *N tasks/sec* in a long term. Since we don't know how many time a task would take before it has completed, it would be incorrect to adjust the algorithm to start N tasks per second (which would result lesser task then that can be started)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I'm not seeing what part of the code make sure it's "in a long term". I'd actually prefer to start N Tasks per second, and not worry about how long they take - if the tasks max out the system and it gets even slower, that's fine. My goal is to say "no more than 10 tasks a second ever"  9 or 8 or 7 is fine, but never 11. How would you recommend changing this code to accomplish that? (I thought it did, but I might have gotten a headache on the `shouldWait` logic :) )

Comment: @Prescott here is 1:40 AM, I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, I 'll work on it myself and post any updates